# linq to sql joining two table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can i do a join in this query to another table

```
 dynamic list = _db.Users.Where(m => m.vcr_UserName != "superadmin"  ).OrderByDescending(m => m.int_UserId).ToPagedList(Cpage, defaultPageSize);
```

i must have a topagedList there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Join(). The tricky part is you must get the keys to be joined on from both tables into the same type to be compared, anonymous types are particularly useful for this.

Signatures are here: http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx

You can find lots of examples (in the more magical from... form) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688085.aspx